# jquery change offset relative to its width

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Is there away to increase to increase a div's offset.left when its width changes. for example am resizing a div element with jQuery resize function `.resize(function)`

Now everything work well but i would like to make the div move the opposite side of resize,. like if am resizing to make it bigger the left offset should extend left and thus lessening the left offset relative to the new width.

---

[image]

Comment: You can probably do it easiest combining with CSS. Can you post code as an example of what you have now?